# Getting at XML files inside Android.jar.res.drawable

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, jar

As I've been researching another problem online, I've seen references to folks modifying the XML files contained inside the Android.jar.res.drawable folder and then copying them to their drawable folder for use in their project.

But I can't open these files, instead I get the following error.

Could not open the editor: org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Editor could not be initialized.

How do I open these files so I can use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Eclipse won't open these files.

I had to search through the Eclipse SDK folder to find the location of the files and then, as mentioned by the other poster, use an alternative text editor in order to open the file.

I then copied this file to my drawable/res folder of my project at which point I could open it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

.jar files are actually just zip files. Easiest thing is to add a ".zip" extension, that is, rename it to android.jar.zip and open with your favourite unzip tool.

EDIT: Oh sorry, I misread your question. Aren't they just plain ASCII XML files then? Open in any text editor you like.

Comment: Yeah, I think I had the same problem before trying to open them within Eclipse. Do yourself a favor and download Notepad++, and open them with that.